# codeigniter website in php not working when moved to different folder

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter, i have a website which is working fine in the domain https://booktheparty.in

i have now moved the complete website to https://molugu.com/btp .  have edited the following files and changed the database information also

> config.php database.php

now the problem is, only home page is displaying in https://molugu.com/btp
rest url are showing internal server error. for example this url https://molugu.com/btp/hyderabad

my htacces file

```html
# HTTPS redirect
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
#</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule> 

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>


<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|html|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</Filesmatch>
</ifmodule>


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

i am really new to this framework, can anyone please tell whats the problem

Comment: check the base url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should modify the `.htaccess` file to also include the subfolder :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^molugu.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.molugu\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ btp/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ btp/index.php?/$1[L,QSA]
```

Comment: hello, i have posted my htacces in question,can you please tell me how to change it